# Analysis of "It is like a dream come true"

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, writing-style

I've been unable to grammatically analyse the sentence

> It is like a dream **come** true.

To me, it should either be

> It is like a dream **that has come** true

or

> It is like a dream **comes** true.

Or peculiarly, *to come true* could be used as a phrase here, and *come true* should be seen as a modifier.

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: Dictionary.com lists it as an "Idiom", definition 25 http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/true

Comment: Related: [A dream come true - is it correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178493)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an [elliptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) form of *a dream that has come true*; you can see it as an example of a [perfect passive participle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Perfect_passive) (i.e. *past participle*).  [English-test.net](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic21092.html#69214) sports a question similar to yours, and one of the answerers posted:

> ...not only is "dream come true" a set expression, but it is also perfectly correct from the grammatical point of view, because, as I'm sure you know, the verb "come" is irregular (come - came,come) whose "infinitive" form is identical to "past participle". Here the expression "to come true" (which means "to materialize, become a reality, become fulfilled" is used with the verb in the "past participle" form by analogy with "girls gone wild" or "teacher turned gangster". In other words, nothing to be surprised or puzzled by, because in this case everything makes perfect sense, even though in language it does not have to be this way.

[Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=877900):

> *[Member 1]*:
>
> I think "come" is a past participle acting acting as an adjective here.
>
> *The dream has come true, it is a dream come true.*
>
> *[Member 2]*:
>
> ...[Member 1]'s explanation is the right one.  In this expression, "come" is a past participle (with the verb "come" here meaning "become"), and the participial phrase "come true" is used as an adjective.
>
> Here are other similar participial phrases used as adjectives:
>
> She was an actress **adored by her fans**, but **thought cold** by those who knew her well.
>
> The billboard was **seen daily** by thousands of people.

So your first explanation is half correct in that *that has come true* can be consolidated to the participial phrase *come true*.  However, your third option is the closest, as evidenced by the explanations I quoted.

Comment: The quote was why I raised this question. My third interpretation is with the claim in this quote, but I'm not sure it's definitive.

Comment: Since it is based on English grammar rules and the forms of *come*, it is certainly definitive.

Comment: So basically, the word "come" is used as a transitive verb in the context? I thought the verb "come" could only be regarded as intransitive. Any other example where "come" is being used in its transitive sense?

Comment: It's not transitive; there isn't an object. Whenever *come* is used to mean *become*, it takes an adjective (as in *came true* or *came untied*), not a noun (i.e. direct object).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, become behaves in a similar way as be does. It makes little sense to me that become could be used as intransitive. Any example about become as intransitive?

Comment: Whenever *become* is used without an object, it is intransitive (e.g. *He became tired* - "tired" is not an object).  When *come* is used to mean *become*, it is **only** used as the intransitive *become*, never the transitive.

Comment: So is "a person become tired" a valid expression as per your theory?

Comment: Yes, though now-a-days that kind of phrasing is either idiomatic or obsolete.  It is nonetheless grammatically valid.

Comment: This conversation's getting long - shall we [continue it in chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1739/discussion-between-dr65--and-terry-liyifeng)

Answer (score 7):

While "come" is indeed a past participle in "dream come true", it is not an ellipsis of "dream that has come true" -- such ellipsis would not be grammatically allowed -- but rather that of "dream **that is** come true". This *archaic* usage of "be" instead of "have" in the *present perfect* applies to certain verbs of motion such as *come, go, rise, set, fall, arrive, depart, grow*, etc., hence we have:

The sun is set.
Our guests are gone. 
Babylon is fallen.
Winter is arrived.
The Lord is come.

Comment: Can you please provide some evidence since yours is somewhat different from the accepted one? If you get it correct, I'll mark yours as accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've always thought of the phrase being *it is like a dream that has come true*, whereupon *that has* is omitted to allow for the past participle *come* to be treated like an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to say 'a dream come true' as it is a reduced form for the adjective clause 'that has come true'. We delete 'that has" and leave the past participle come (come-came-**come**).

Answer (score 0):

a dream come true"

This does not mean "It's a dream that comes true".

It is a phrase. To "come true" means to become a reality or to materialise.

It would be a dream come true. (come is the infinitive)
It was a dream come true (come is in the past participle)

Come /came / come.

Another example is:

The good guy went bad / he is a good guy gone bad

"Come " is not a doing work or verb in this instance. Its a set of adjective phrase.Its a descriptive word for "dream" not a doing word for "dream". Neither the word "dream" here is positioned as a doer/actor. Hope this explanation enlightens your ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

I think 'It is like a dream come true,' is originally ' ------ a dream (that is) come true.'  When an ellipse is applied, the result becomes 'It is like a dream come true.'