# A dream come true - is it correct

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, past-tense

I was confused by a company slogan I saw, and that made me wonder: **Is it correct to write "a dream come true"?**

If I was the one writing it I would use "a dream comes true" but is the initial form wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is correct. *Come* is a past participle here, not a simple present. It means *a dream [that has/is] come true*. The past participle *come* can be used with the verb *be*, which is why *a dream come true* is possible; this is normally possible with all verbs that can be or once could be used with *be*.

> a horse [that was] left behind
>
> a day [that has/is] gone by

Answer (score 0):

"A dream come true" 
 "Come" is the past participle form of the Irregular verb "come". It is in a verb form but used as participle  modifier of the word "dream". A participle modifier is a verb form but used as a modifier or an adjective.  So, the word "come" describes or tells something about the word "dream". It's just like saying " A project done well".

A dream come true- a dream that has come true 
A project done well- a project that has done well  or a project that is done well.